# Passing Variable Entity type to a ViewModel

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a ViewModel for an edit screen in a SL4 RIA Service solution that looks like this:

```cs
public GenericEditViewModel (int intA, string strB, RIA_EntityA entityObj) 
{
    ......
}
```

I am using this same viewmodel to edit several entities, such that the type of entityObj is not constant. How can I use the same ViewModel Constructor to handle calls for, say, `RIA_EntityB`, `RIA_EntityC`.......? 
I tried generics, but that did not seem to work?

Thanks !

Comment: this seems like an issue better solved with generics. can you expand on how did you try to do this with generics and what didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use command and command's parameter instead of VM's constructor.

Also you can look [this](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/208399/489780.aspx) discussion